# What causes angular delay specially in UI?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The page takes a bit longer to load and for around 2-3 seconds the UI is destroyed as you can see on the screenshot 1 before it loaded , I have checked the data and the data is not that heavy.

What causes that issue that when the page loaded it is destroyed for around 2-3 seconds and after that the UI is already okay ?

Why is that it took 2-3 seconds for the UI to be loaded ? is there something wrong from my implementation ?

I hope someone can enlighten me with this one , it was bugging me for a couple of days. Thanks.

#This is how it longs every time the page is loaded but only for 2-3 seconds

[SCREENSHOT 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgPK6.png)

#after 2 - 3 seconds the UI is now is normal see screenshot 2

[SCREENSHOT2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjOPM.png)

#html code snippet

```
<div class="header fixed" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <!-- breadcrumb -->
    <div class="breadcrumb clear">
        <ul>
            <li>Settings</li>
            <li>Manage Users & Teams </li>
            <li>User Profile: {{fullName}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- back button -->
    <button mat-button class="back-button" (click)="navigateBack()">
        <mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon>
        Back to Users
    </button>

    <!-- page title -->
    <div class="page-title">User Profile</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="sidemenu-container">
        <div class="card sidemenu">
            <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <img class="avatar" src="{{userProfileIcon}}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="username" style="margin-top: 10px;">{{fullName}}</div>
            <div class="usertitle">{{this.data.title}}</div>
            <div class="menu-items">
                <div class="center" [class.active]="currentTabElement === 'general'">
                    <button (click)="scrollTo(generalCard)" mat-button>
                        General
                    </button>
                    <div class="scroll-indicator"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="center" [class.active]="currentTabElement ==='security'">
                    <button (click)="scrollTo(securityCard)" mat-button>
                        Security Role and SSO
                    </button>
                    <div class="scroll-indicator"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="center" [class.active]="currentTabElement==='password'">
                    <button (click)="scrollTo(passwordCard)" mat-button>
                        Password and Login
                    </button>
                    <div class="scroll-indicator"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="center" [class.active]="currentTabElement ==='teams'">
                    <button (click)="scrollTo(teamsCard)" mat-button>
                        Teams
                    </button>
                    <div class="scroll-indicator"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="center" [class.active]="scrollElementId==='transactions'">
                    <button (click)="scrollTo(transactionsCard)" mat-button>
                        Transactions
                    </button>
                    <div class="scroll-indicator"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <div class="center mt1">
                <button (click)="activateUserDialog(this.data.status)" mat-button class="w100 deactivate-user">
                    <mat-icon> {{this.data.status === 'Deactivated' ? 'play_circle_filled' : 'pause_circle_filled'}}
                    </mat-icon>
                    {{this.data.status === 'Deactivated' ? 'Reactivate user' : 'Deactivate user'}}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="scroll-container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="anchor" id="general" #generalCard></div>
            <div class="card-header">
                <mat-icon
                    [ngClass]="{'card-icon':currentTabElement !== 'general', 'active-icon':currentTabElement === 'general'}">
                    {{generalForm.enabled ? 'supervised_user_circle' : 'supervised_user_circle'}}</mat-icon>
                <div class="title">GENERAL</div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <button mat-button *ngIf="generalForm.disabled" (click)="editGeneralInfo()">
                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon> Edit
                </button>
                <button mat-button *ngIf="generalForm.enabled" (click)="generalForm.disable()">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button mat-stroked-button
                    [disabled]="userStatus !== 'USER_ON_NO_ACCOUNT' && generalForm.get('emailAddress').value !== this.data.emailAddress"
                    *ngIf="generalForm.enabled" (click)="saveGeneralFormChanges()">
                    Save Changes
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="generalForm.disabled" (click)="foldGeneral = !foldGeneral">
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="foldGeneral">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="!foldGeneral">keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" *ngIf="!foldGeneral">
                <ng-template [ngIf]="generalForm.disabled">
                    <div class="line-item">
                        <div class="title">EMAIL</div>
                        <div class="detail">{{this.data.emailAddress}}</div>
                        <mat-icon [class.mr-90]="this.data.emailAddress.length > 25" class="active"
                            [style.color]="(this.data.status == 'Accepted' || this.data.status == 'Active' ) ? '#00B0DB' : '#BDBDBD'">
                            {{ (this.data.status == 'Accepted' || this.data.status == 'Active' ) ? 'check_circle' :
                            'check_circle_outline' }}</mat-icon>
                        <button
                            *ngIf="this.data.status !== 'Active' && this.data.status !== 'Deactivated'  && this.data.status !== 'Accepted'"
                            (click)="resendWelcomeEmailDialog()" mat-button class="detail active">Resend welcome
                            email</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="line-item">
                        <div class="title">FIRST NAME</div>
                        <div class="detail">{{this.data.firstName}}</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="line-item">
                        <div class="title">LAST NAME</div>
                        <div class="detail">{{this.data.lastName}}</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="line-item">
                        <div class="title">PHONE NUMBER</div>
                        <div class="detail">+1 {{this.data.phoneNumber}}</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="line-item">
                        <div class="title">COMPANY NAME</div>
                        <div class="detail">{{this.data.companyName || 'None'}}</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="line-item">
                        <div class="title">TITLE</div>
                        <div class="detail">{{this.data.title || 'None'}}</div>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </div>
```

#typescript code

```
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading: boolean;
  userId: number;
  isInProgress: boolean;
  data: any;  role:string;
  foldGeneral = false;
  foldSecurity = false;
  foldPassword = false;
  foldTeams = false;
  foldTransactions = false;

  panelOpenState = false;
  @ViewChild(MatAccordion) accordion: MatAccordion;
  AccountRoleIsInProgress: boolean;
  accountRoles: Array<any> = [];
  selectedRole: any;
  defaultRole: any;
  roleId: FormControl;
  fullName: string;
  constructor(
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _notificationService: NotificationService,
    private _userProfileService: UserProfileService,
    private builder: AnimationBuilder,
    private _router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _teamService: TeamService,
    private _accountService: AccountService,

    private scroller: ViewportScroller,
    
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this.generalForm.disable();
    this.securityForm.disable();
    this.passwordForm.disable();
    this.roleId = new FormControl();
    
  }

  pageHeaderTitleData = {
    title:{
      primary: "User Profile"
    }
  }
  breadCrumbsData = {
    paths:[
      {
        text: "Settings",
      }
    ],
    currentPage: 'Manage Users & Teams'
  }

  generalForm = new FormGroup({
    emailAddress: new FormControl(),
    firstName: new FormControl(),
    lastName: new FormControl(),
    phoneNumber: new FormControl(),
    companyName: new FormControl(),
    title: new FormControl(),
  });

  securityForm = new FormGroup({
    isSso: new FormControl(),
    ssocredentials: new FormControl(),
    roleId: new FormControl(),
  });

  passwordForm = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(),
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pageHeaderTitleData.title.primary = "User Profile"
    const currentAccountDetails = localStorage.getItem('currAcct') as any;
    if (currentAccountDetails) {
      this.accountId = JSON.parse(currentAccountDetails).accountId;
    }

    this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      this.userId = params.id;
      this.getUserGeneralDetails();
      this.getAccountRoleDropdown();
    });
  }
```

#code for getting the data

```
getUserGeneralDetails() {
    this.isInProgress = true;
    this._userProfileService
      .getUserGeneralDetails(this.userId, this.accountId)
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false)))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          if (res.isSuccess) {
            this.data = res.data;
            this.fullName = this.data.firstName + " " + this.data.lastName;
            this.userProfileIcon = `https://ui-avatars.com/api/?size=48&name=${this.data.firstName}+${this.data.lastName}&rounded=true&background=bdbdbd&color=ffffff`;
            this.AccountRoleDetails = this.accountRoles.find(o=>o.id == this.data.roleId);
          }
        },
        error: (err) => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
```

#data being loaded

```
{
    "id": 92,
    "emailAddress": "adasdas@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "asdasd",
    "lastName": "asdasd",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "associatedAccount": "WLG",
    "status": "Invited",
    "lastLogIn": null,
    "invitedById": null,
    "invitedByDate": "08/19/2021 11:09 AM",
    "identityId": "75312f0d-96dc-497b-a321-81dcae56b0d0",
    "title": "asdasd",
    "companyName": "asdasd",
    "isSso": null,
    "ssocredentials": "",
    "userAccountDto": [
        {
            "id": 96,
            "accountId": 4,
            "accountName": "Wasdas",
            "displayName": "asdas",
            "userRoleDto": {
                "id": 2,
                "roleName": "Broker"
            },
            "accountDto": {
                "accountId": 4,
                "accountName": "sfdsds"
                "displayName": "asdas
                "isActive": true,
                "contactFirstName": null,
                "contactLastName": null,
                "contactPhone": null,
                "contactEmailAddress": null,
                "accountRoleDto": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "accountId": 4,
                        "roleName": "Broker"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "accountId": 4,
                        "roleName": "Admin"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "accountId": 4,
                        "roleName": "Transaction Manager"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "accountId": 4,
                        "roleName": "Transaction Super User"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "accountId": 4,
                        "roleName": "Unlicensed User"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "accountId": 0,
    "roleId": 2,
    "isVerified": false,
    "securityRole": "Broker",
    "ssoEnabled": "No",
    "passwordLastChanged": "",
    "lastLoggedIn": "",
    "teamsDto": [],
    "associatedTransactionDetailsDto": []
}
```

Comment: Into the browser, take a look at the Network tab, and see how long the request you get is in `pending` state

Comment: @Emilien , when I checked the network , the request is fast and the data is already present but the UI is still destroyed for around 2 -3 seconds

Comment: Also your code seems very massive. It will not solve your issue, but maybe ou can split your code into small components, it will allow you to debug easily. Maybe the problem come from modules imports.

Comment: Can you check the console? Any error message

Comment: I check the browser console it says at first "core.js:6162 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" but title exists on the data object

Comment: or is this because of the enable and disable of Forms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think use loading, so when your all data is fetched then and only then you will get the UI and it's the way.

show loading in the getUserGeneralDetails() function's first line and then hide loading after subscribe.